# C++11 pass by value of POD type worse than const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

This question is NOT about passing large objects by value or reference -- and also not about move semantics -- like many other questions around.

I wanted to know how small a POD type has to be so that it is a better idea to pass it by value rather than by const reference. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

using Number = double; //complex<double>;

struct acc {
  Number a;
  void f(const Number& x) { a += x; }
  void g(Number x) { a += x; }
};

int main()
{
  int n = 1000000000;
  Number *v = new Number[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    v[i] = Number(i);
  }

  clock_t b, e;
  acc foo;

#ifdef _const
  b = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    foo.f(v[i]);

  e = clock();

  cout << ((double) e - b) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
#else
  b = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    foo.g(v[i]);

  e = clock();

  cout << ((double) e - b) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
#endif

  cout << foo.a << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled with gcc without optimization.

When using Number = complex, const reference was faster, and I expected that a bit. But pass by const reference was also faster when using Number = double, which completely surprises me (in my computer, it was 3.5 for pass-by-value and 2.9 for const reference).

Why is this? Isn't the amount of work, including memory access, the same in such a simple example? I have to write a template library, and I wanted to be careful and use const references or pass-by-value depending on the size of the template arguments, but now I think it is rather useless to worry about this. Anyone else has any idea what is going on?

If I compile with optimization, then both varieties run equally fast.

Comment: "*I compiled with gcc without optimization.*" That is the problem. It isn't worth spending too much time worrying about relative performance of unoptimized code.

Comment: "If I compile with optimization, then both varieties run equally fast."
So what do you want?

Comment: I vote to close this question because it doesn't ask about any discernible problem.

Comment: This is a very simple program. If I compile with the optimizer turned on, then the function call will be inlined. In a program where the methods of class acc are complicaed, the calls won't be inlined. This makes a huge difference!

Comment: It is still completely pointless to do what you're doing.

Comment: Comparing unoptimized builds is pointless. If you want to compare this, then use optimization, and use a technique to avoid inlining. Like putting the implementation in other translation unit. Or use a compiler specific noinline attribute.

Comment: Theoretically, passing tiny objects by value in optimized code could be faster if the objects have local storage duration, fit in machine registers (a prerequisite is no address is ever taken), and the code is to big to be inlined. Especially on x64, where the calling convention prefers passing first few arguments via registers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess the the only way to really know is to write the real code using both options and see which one is best.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler writers do not care care if your unoptimized toy code is 20% slower in one similar case to another.  That is why.

Neither should you, unless you are in an extreme corner case where you need your debug build to be fast enough to hit some soft realtime requirements (say, finish a render every X Hz, or process data before the other end of a network connection times out) and that 20% slowdown is on a critical path.